# Trying to install KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization

```
hwr44ever@hwr44ever-Latitude-D630:~$ sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin bridge-utils virt-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bridge-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bridge-utils' has no installation candidate

E: Unable to locate package virt-manager`
```

Comment: obviously, you did not run the command with sudo. Try "sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin bridge-utils virt-manager"

Comment: Make sure you have the "Universe" repository enabled in your system's Software Sources or by running `sudo add-apt-repository universe`. Then try your command again.